# How to add an icon in a text field without touching the css code?

Tags: html, frontend

I want to add a checkmark in the username field and make it appears when the username is not taken and a second one (a warning icon or smth) that appears when the username is taken. I don't want to touch the css code.

HTML:

```
 <div class="form-group" id="username-group">
        <label><%= l('Username') %></label>
        <%= text_field 'username', rel => 'username', class => 'form-control',
            required => undef, pattern => "[a-zA-Z0-9._]{4,15}" %>
        <div class="valid-feedback" id="username-check-taken"
             style="display:none;"><%= l("Username is already in use.") %></div>
        <div class="form-control-feedback" style="display:none;"
             ><%= l("Can contain alphanumeric characters, _, " .
             ". and the length must be between 4 and 15 characters") %></div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid touching the CSS code? The best way to do this would be adding a background to the input with CSS when a class is present.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a package that will provide a set of icons, whose classes you can include in your HTML elements to make things easier.
Check out https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>

<i class="material-icons">cloud</i>
<i class="material-icons">favorite</i>
<i class="material-icons">attachment</i>
<i class="material-icons">computer</i>
<i class="material-icons">traffic</i>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is a good idea to use a form-row to place the icon next to the text field?

Comment: By 'form-row' if you mean the Bootstrap Form class and you are fine with the layout it provides, its up to you to use it. I would go for a simple solution like below if I have to implement your need.                                                              <div>
<span>Check Icon here</span>
<span>Textbox here</span>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

If you can use JavaScript, maybe this little code will help you :

```js
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function(e) {
let username = $(this).val();
let wariningIconUrl = 'http://www.pngall.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Alert-Download-PNG.png';
let checkIconUrl = 'https://img.favpng.com/25/17/2/check-mark-computer-icons-clip-art-png-favpng-FRDM9ia5q695puSB2mSJEsSKG.jpg'
  
let imgWarn = document.createElement("img");
let imgOk = document.createElement("img");
    let inputWidth = $(this).width();
  
$(imgWarn).attr("src",wariningIconUrl).css({"width":"13px","position":"absolute"})
  $(imgOk).attr("src",checkIconUrl).css({"width":"13px","position":"absolute"})
  let offset = $("#myInput").offset();
  
     
  let taken = false //code to check if username is already taken (maybe ajax request if then include the bottom code in your done function of ajax)
  
  
if(taken == true){
  $(".form-group").append($(imgWarn).css("left",offset.left+inputWidth-20).css("top",offset.top+5));
} else {
  $(".form-group").append($(imgOk).css("left",offset.left+inputWidth-20).css("top",offset.top+5));
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group" id="username-group">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="myInput"/>
    <div class="valid-feedback" id="username-check-taken" style="display:none;">
      Username is already in use
    </div>
    <div class="form-control-feedback" style="display:none;">
      Can contain alphanumeric characters, and the length must be between 4 and 15 characters
    </div>
</div>
```

Change the code to match your needs, to check if the username if taken or not

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

**You can add below html code to show the warning icon:**

```
<span style='font-size:20px;color: red;'>&#9888;</span>
```

**You can use below html code to show the success icon:**

```
<span style='font-size:20px;color: green;'>&#10004;</span>
```

By using html entities you don't need to use/call icon fonts file.

SRC: 
https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_dingbats.asp & https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp